# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error when scraping long and lat value of states

Tags: r

I have a list of American states stored in a .csv file:

```
cities <- read.csv("cities.csv")
states <- fetch_cities$states
df_total_US <- data.frame(state = character(), lon = character(), lat = character())
```

states <- as.character(cities$States)

Now I would like to loop over the states and fetch their longitude and latitude value. Therefore I do:

```
   for(state in states){
     df_temp <- geocode(state)
     df_add <- data.frame(state = state, lon = df_temp$lon[1], lat = df_temp$lat[1])
     df_total_US <- rbind(df_add, df_total_US)
     Sys.sleep(5) 
   }
```

This however gives several warnings() saying:

```
geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = ...
```

I thought I could get rid of this error by including:\

```
sys.sleep(5)
```

But clearly this is not working. Any suggestions for what I should do to scrape the coordinates of a list?

Comment: The query limit is 2500 per day

Comment: This is a frustrating problem I'm encountering, as well, when relying on `ggmap::geocode( source = "google")`. Here's an [alternative approach using `source=dsk`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282492/ggmap-dsk-rate-limit).

[Batch Geocoding with R and Google maps](https://www.shanelynn.ie/massive-geocoding-with-r-and-google-maps/) seems promising.

I would suggest  _Geolocation/Geocoding_ sub-section within the [Data Analysis and Processing Services section in CRAN's Tools for Working with the Web from R](https://cran.r-project.org/view=WebTechnologies) for alternative packages.